# Cassandra, how to filter and update a big table dynamically?

Tags: database, database-design, cassandra

I'm trying to find the best data model to adapt a very big mysql table in Cassandra.
This table is structured like this:

```
CREATE TABLE big_table (
  social_id, 
  remote_id,
  timestamp,
  visibility,
  type,
  title,
  description,
  other_field,
  other_field,
  ...
  )
```

A page (which is not here) can contain many socials, which can contain many remote_ids.

Social_id is the partitioning key, remote_id and timestamp are the clustering key: "Remote_id" gives unicity, "Time" is used to order the results. So far so good.

The problem is that users can also search on their page contents, filtering by one or more socials, one or more types, visibility (could be 0,1,2), a range of dates or even nothing at all.
Plus, based on the filters, users should be able to set visibility.

I tried to handle this case, but I really can find a sustainable solution.
The best I've got is to create another table, which I need to keep up with the original one.
This table will have:

- page_id: partition key
- timestamp, social_id, type, remote_id: clustering key

Plus, create a Materialized View for each combination of filters, which is madness.

Can I avoid creating the second table? What wuold be the best Cassandra model in this case? Should I consider switching to other technologies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I start from last questions.

*> What would be the best Cassandra model in this case?*

As stated in [Cassandra: The Definitive Guide, 2nd edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920043041.do) (which I highly recommend to read before choosing or using Cassandra),

> In Cassandra you don’t start with the data model; **you start with the query model**.

You may want to read an available chapter about data design at [Safaribooksonline.com](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/cassandra-the-definitive/9781449399764/ch04.html). Basically, Cassandra wants you to think about queries only and don't care about normalization.

So the answer on

*> Can I avoid creating the second table?*

is **You shouldn't avoiding it**.

*> Should I consider switching to other technologies?*

That depends on what you need in terms of replication and partitioning. You may end up creating master-master synchronization based on RDBMS or something else. In Cassandra, you'll end up with duplicated data between tables and that's perfectly normal for it. You trade disk space in exchange for reading/writing speed.

*> how to filter and update a big table dynamically?*

If after all of the above you still want to use normalized data model in Cassandra, I suggest you look on [secondary indexes](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useSecondaryIndex.html) at first and then move on to custom indexes like [Lucene index](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index).

Comment: Ok for the replication of content, but how would you model the table with the problem I stated (multiple dynamic filters)? Would you create a table for every combination of filters? Or a table plus many materialized views? What is the best model handling this case?

Comment: An example from Cassandra: TDG book suggests you to pre-define queries your users will be using (example from the book: searching `hotel` by `name` or `free_rooms count`) and create tables for each query. Whatever queries were not pre-defined will require you to either `SELECT *;` and work through this on the app side or to use secondary indexes.

Comment: However, the secondary index is not recommended for columns with unique values (the index will equal to column) and for columns with a few different values (e.g. `gender` column).

Comment: Basically, Cassandra model (as opposite to RDBMS) won't let you do parsing and filtering at database side. That's intentional to provide extremely fast reads and writes for enormous amounts of data.

Comment: Yes, I'm indeed evaluating other technologies like MongoDB, which seems more flexible for this use case. Fastest writes/reads has a cost in terms of "data analysis"... and Cassandra seems to be a great fit where you have huge raw data (which will be then processed by other technologies). Thanks for the support!